# Convert int to string in hexadecimal format [C++]

Tags: string, hex

I have an integer in hexadecimal format that I want to convert to a string.

for example, int __checkSum = cb;

I want string s to equal "cb";

How do I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string string0 = "09";
    string string1 = "09";
    string string2 = "00BB";
    string string3 = "00FE";
    int checkSum0 = stoi(string0, 0, 16);
    int checkSum1 = stoi(string1, 0, 16);
    int checkSum2 = stoi(string2, 0, 16);
    int checkSum3 = stoi(string3, 0, 16);
    int _checkSum = checkSum0 + checkSum1 + checkSum2 +checkSum3;
    
    int __checkSum = _checkSum & 0xFF;
    
    string s = to_string(__checkSum);

    
    cout << hex <<_checkSum << endl;
    cout << hex << __checkSum << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
}
```